# Spring Data ES query by nested object date field

Tags: spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

Using `Spring Data ES`.

I have an index named `ship` with following definition:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

@Document(indexName = "ship", type = "journey")
public class ShipJourney {

    @Id
    private String shipId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<ShipLocation> shipLocation;

    //getters and setters
}
```

`ShipLocation` is a nested object defined as:

```
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class ShipLocation {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private LocalDateTime recordedOnTime;

    //setters and getters
}
```

I want to find a ship location just before or equal to `LocalDateTime` parameter.

I tried this:

```
ShipJourney findTopByShipIdAndShipLocationRecordedOnTimeLessThanOrderByShipLocationRecordedOnTimeDesc(
        String shipId, LocalDateTime recordedOnTime);
```

only to realise later that I was using `Top` on the `ShipJourney` itself which will be eventually one record only due to the `shipId's` uniqueness.

How can I limit the data I get for the nested element based on one of its attribute?

Comment: That repo method name is quite a story. Remember me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible with the Spring Data ElasticSearch repositories. If you can autowire `ElasticSearchTemplate`, your query could look something like this (untested):

```
String shipId = "A";
LocalDateTime recordedOnTime = LocalDateTime.now();
int maxShipLocations = 3; // <-- TOP

NestedQueryBuilder findByLocation = nestedQuery("shipLocation", rangeQuery("shipLocation.recordedOnTime").lt(recordedOnTime));
TermQueryBuilder findById = termQuery("id", shipId);
QueryBuilder findByIdAndLocation = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .filter(findById) 
        .filter(findByLocation.innerHit(new QueryInnerHitBuilder().setSize(maxShipLocations)));

SearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withIndices("ship")
        .withTypes("journey")
        .withQuery(findByIdAndLocation)
        .withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("shipLocation.recordedOnTime").order(SortOrder.DESC))
        .build();
List<ShipJourney> shipJourney = elasticSearchTemplate.queryForList(query, ShipJourney.class);
```